# Using stopwatch and it doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, stopwatch, discord

I'm using discord bot, and I'm trying to check the time of the time service but its only shows the time only once and then writes 0

```
public async Task HandleCommand(SocketMessage messageParam)
{
    // Don't process the command if it was a System Message
    var message = messageParam as SocketUserMessage;

    if (message == null || message.Author.IsBot) 
       return;

    Console.WriteLine(message.Author);
    time.Start();

    // Create a number to track where the prefix ends and the command begins
    int argPos = 0;

    // Determine if the message is a command, based on if it starts with '!' or a mention prefix
    if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('>', ref argPos))) 
        return;

    // Create a Command Context
    var context = new CommandContext(dbot, message);
    Last = message.Author;

    // Execute the command. (result does not indicate a return value, 
    // rather an object stating if the command executed successfully)
    var result = await commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, services);

    time.Stop();
    time.Reset();
}
```

and it calls this function

```
[Command("ping"), Summary("Echos a message.")]
public async Task Say()
{
    // ReplyAsync is a method on ModuleBase
    await ReplyAsync("PONG " + CommandHandler.time.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: You are resetting the stopwatch directly after starting the new thread. This means the stopwatch is already resetted if the other thread checks the value.

Comment: Are you missing a `time.Start();` after resetting the timer?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating timer inside async function.